# How to manipulate autowired object inside a configuration class during startup and use later?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, nullpointerexception

I have a configuration class that establishes a connection with a database and populates several objects with information from the database. I want to autowire these objects for use later. The structure of the classes is something like this:

```
@Repository
RedisObject

@Configuration   
Configuration class
     @Autowire RedisObject in here and populate bean

Normal Class
     @Autowire RedisObject to capture and use bean
```

I keep getting nullpointers, what am I doing wrong? Sorry if bad question, new to spring.

Comment: I don't understand the issue, can you give a more detailed example or try to be more specific.

Comment: share the class structure not the snippet in which you are getting an error.

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope I have a class which I want to populate during runtime some fields of a bean (object). I want to use that object in another class during runtime, but i keep getting nullpointers.

Answer (score 2):

Guys that have left answers are right- not enough info.
But following your example I can say,that the Spring is right. 
Your `NormalClass` is not a bean, so it doesn't get into container. And that is a reason you can't autowire any beans within it. Only the beans inside a container can be autowired.